# How to show current time that should change every second or minute in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, current-time

I am working on an angular 11 project.
I want to display current time and date and the time should change for every minute.

I tried with `new Date()`. But it shows only the time when the program run time.

This is what I tried. But it does not works for me

.ts file

```
  today= Date.now();
  UKDataTime = '';

  this.UKDataTime = formatDate(this.today, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0100');
```

.html file

```
 <p class="current-time">UK: {{UKDataTime}}</p>
```

What can i do display live time in angular 11?

Comment: You can find similar question [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155944/angular-2-clock-with-rxjs-observable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change date value every second for example you can use `setInterval` for this

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.UKDataTime = formatDate(Date.now(), 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0100');
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rxjs `timer`

```
timer(0,1000).pipe(map(x => new Date())).subscribe(console.log);
```